# Gayatri mantra mudras?

Tags: gayatri-mantra, sandhyavandanam, mudra

How to do Mudras before chanting Gayatri mantra? 
[This Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Gayatri-Mantra-locked-How-do-you-unlock-it/answer/Abhijith-Sharma-1) gives mantra to unlock Gayatri mantra. 
[This Facebook image](https://m.facebook.com/Brahmins/photos/gayatri-japa-mudrasit-is-prescribed-that-24-mudrashand-guestures-are-to-be-displ/10151440050507617/) describes 24 Mudras to be done next 
As well as instructions /mantras written in Sanskrit 
But Can someone transcribe & translate the mantras to English, roman characters? I can't read Sanskrit script.

Comment: Visit http://www.awgp.org/spiritual_wisdom/gayatri/activation_of_internal_power_centres_by_gayatri_sadhan

Answer (score 4):

In the Gayatri Mantra Upashana practicing 24 Mudras (hand postures) have been prescribed. The names of the Mudras can be found in the following passage from the [**Devi Bhagavatam's 11th Book's chapter 16**](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam61.htm):

> Gâyatrî has seven S’iras (heads); Vyâkaranam (Grammar) is one; S’iksâ
>   is the second (that Amga of the Veda, the science which teaches the
>   proper pronunciation of words and laws of euphony); Kalpa is the third
>   (the Vedânga which lays down the ritual and prescribes rules for
>   ceremonial and sacrificial acts); Nirukta is the fourth (the Vedânga
>   that contains glossarial explanation of obscure words, especially
>   those occurring in the Vedas); Jyotish or astronomy is the fifth;
>   Itahâsa (history) and Purânas is the sixth head; and Upanisadas is the
>   seventh head. Agni (fire) is the mouth of Gâyatrî; Rudra is the S’ikhâ
>   (the chief part); Her gotra (lineage) is Sâmkhyâyana; Visnu is the
>   heart of Gâyatrî and Brahmâ is the armour of Gâyatrî. Think of this
>   Mahes’varî Gâyatrî in the middle of the Solar Orb. **Meditating on the
>   Gâyatrî Devî as above, the devotee should shew the following
>   twenty-four Mudrâs (signs by the fingers, etc., in religious worship)
>   for the satisfaction of the Devî :-- (1) Sanmukh; (2) Sampût; (3)
>   Vitata (4) Vistrita; (5) Dvîmukha; (6) Trimukha; (7) Chaturmukha; (8)
>   Panchamukha; (9) Sanmukha; (10) Adhomukha; (11) Vyâpaka; (12) Anjali;
>   (13) S’akata (14) Yamapâs’a; (15) fingers intertwined end to end; (16)
>   Vilamba (17) Mustika; (18) Matsya; (19) Kûrma; (20) Varâha; (21)
>   Simhâkrânta; (22) Mahâkrânta; (23) Mudgara; (24) Pallava**. Next make
>   japam once only of one hundred syllabled Gâyatrî. Thus twenty-four
>   syllabled Sâvitrî, “Jâtavedase sunavâma, etc.,” forty-four syllabled
>   mantra; and the thirty two syllabled mantra, “Tryamvakam Jajâmahe,
>   etc.” These three mantras united make up one hundred lettered Gâyatrî.

**UPDATE:**

[This Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19iGsGXYsOs) describes how to do the 24 Mudras very well. The video also gives the names of all the Mudras in the correct order which is already given in my answer.

Comment: Yes, please................

Comment: @Aoi.T_015 See the video I hv added in the answer. You can learn the Mudras from it.

Comment: @Aoi.T_015 since This has provided an answer and it is satisfactory it would be nice if you could press the tick (✔️), below the voting arrows. It lets other users know that this answer is correct and satisfies the question the most. You will also get additional reputation if you accept.